# meaning of the argmax in max-plus semiring (or tropical semiring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

The max-plus semiring:$(\{\mathbb{R}\cup{-\infty}\}, max,+):=(\{\mathbb{R}\cup{-\infty}\}, \oplus, \otimes)$ is defined as an algebraic structure that has max as addition and + as multiplication.

My question is what "argmax" means in this semiring or algebraic structure.

I have never seen the explanation.

Common addition doesn't have accompanied structure like "argmax".
But I think "argmax" is not only a necessary accompanied structure of the max-plus semiring but also important information we often use.

Does anyone explain how should we understand argmax from algebraic viewpoint?

Comment: argmax is not part of the semiring structure (and is not always uniquely defined anyway). Are you looking for a souped-up notion of semirings that does involve an argmax operation? That might be an interesting question (dendriform algebras do something like this perhaps).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you very much for the comment.
I think max-plus semiring could formulate some problem very concisely, e.g. the problem is convex optimization and the argmin/argmax is unique.
That's why I want argmax structure is accompanied it.
Otherwise, we have to treat argmax object with another method that is not closely bound the semiring.